# dereferencing error in linked list - not typedef error

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I can't find my dereferencing error to save my life. As far as I can see I've got all my declarations where they need to be and can't see where I have defined a bad structure.

EDIT: the paste is missing a ton of the code, but it includes all of the code that uses the pointers. everything else is checking to make sure the file is the right file, right location, error handling, etc.

```
typedef struct list{
int pid;
char *name;
struct list* link;
}LIST;

void begin(FILE *file, char *argv[])
{
  struct LIST *root, *p, *tail;
  struct utmp x[BUFF];
  root = NULL;
  char *name;
  int c;
  int i;
  struct utmp hold;
  int pid;
  tail = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
  int logins = 0;
  int logouts = 0;
  for (i=0;i<=BUFF;i++)
    {
      c = fread(x, sizeof(struct utmp), BUFF, file);
      if (strcmp(x[i].ut_user, argv[1]) == 0)
        {
          if (x[i].ut_type == 7)
            {
              hold = x[i];
              logins++;
              pid = x[i].ut_pid;
              name = hold.ut_user;
              p = create(pid, name); //<--Line 129 
              if (root == NULL)
                {
                root = tail = p;
                }
              else
                {
                  tail->link = p; //<---Line 136
                  tail = p;
                }
              printf("%d\n", p->pid); //<---Line 139
            }
        }
      if (x[i].ut_pid == pid && x[i].ut_type == 8)
        {
          pid = 0;
          logouts++;
        }
    }


LIST *create(int pid, char *name)
{
  LIST *p;
  p = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
  p->pid = pid;
  p->link = NULL;
  p->name = name;
  return p;
}
```

The error:

```
main.c: In function ‘begin’:
main.c:129:10: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
main.c:136:9: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
main.c:139:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code here instead of giving a reference.

Comment: And also show the exact error message, and which line it's on.

Comment: `for (i=0;i < BUFF;i++)`

Comment: @joop Post that as an answer?

Comment: I take it back. It didn't work.

Comment: No there is more wrong in the fragment (such as the fread() inside the for loop) BTW: I don't want the points. Too easy ...

Comment: @MichaelWalz - the lines are marked in the program.

Comment: @joop Could you please iterate on the for loop problem?

Comment: Put following declaration before the `begin` function: `LIST *create(int pid, char *name) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with confusing how to use structs and typedefs.  Your definition

```
typedef struct list{
...
}LIST;
```

creates 2 data types the structure `struct list` and its typedef equivalent `LIST`.  Then when you declare your variables, you use `struct LIST`, which isn't defined.  This is generating all 3 of your errors.  The compiler is assuming that you are defining this struct somewhere else.  The reason that people use `typedef` is to make the later use of `struct` unnecessary.